# Is there a free licence or alternative pathway for a solo developer to release an app using DX?

Tags: appexchange, salesforcedx, developer, app-development

So I'm currently working as a Salesforce developer. I have a few ideas for apps /cli plugins that I'd like to develop and release in my own time.

To do this in the way I want to work, I need:
 - Vs code / git setup (check).
 - CLI set up. (check).
 - Free or Dev only Salesforce org to enable a permanent/full Dev hub. (Nope).

However it strikes me that Salesforce development under the new DX umbrella is geared towards companies with existing Salesforce licences. You can't use a trailhead dev org to develop a plugin for example. I need a production org with a permanently enabled dev hub.

The trial hub is great for exploring but not suitable for more complex development (and is, you know, a trial!).

Is there any alternative to buying a licence just for myself? This would be prohibitive for me at this time, but would be helpful to know so I don't spend more time on this (and I'll go back to C# instead) :)

Please note I am not asking about non-compete clauses, how to develop solo, the merits of whether the company should enable this kind of work (all good questions :) ). I'm only asking about the access to tools for solo development and minimum required licences, if any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While SFDX is geared towards being used with scratch orgs (which, as I'm sure you already know, requires a dev hub org), *you can use the Salesforce CLI without them* (and without a dev hub org).

Instead of using `sfdx force:source:push` all the time, you'll be using the following sequence:

- develop some code, and save it
- convert to metadata api form with `sfdx force:source:convert -d <destination directory>`
- deploy to your (free) developer edition org with `sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -d <same directory as the last step> -u <username or alias for your target org>`

When you get down to it, this flow is similar to what people used to do with the Force.com Migration Tool (using Apache ANT).

The one big drawback I find to this approach is that the error messages that `force:mdapi:deploy` returns are pretty terrible (at least for now). Unless you jump through a few hoops to extend the sfdx integration with vscode [like Bob Buzzard has](http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.com/2018/01/sfdx-and-metadata-api-part-4-vscode.html), I don't think errors from a metadata api deployment have accessible line numbers attached to those errors.

Comment: While I'd prefer that there was something like how other development platforms enable full developer access, this looks to cover everything I asked, thanks.